# Typesetting critical footnotes in reledpar package from right to left

Tags: reledmac, xepersian, reledpar

I want to typeset two Persian (Arabic) text in parallel facing pages with reledpar and `xepersian` packages. I have done but critical footnotes is written from left to right. How I can have critical footnotes from right to left?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\usepackage[series={A}]{reledmac}
\usepackage[top=3cm,left=5cm,right=4cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[shiftedpstarts,nomaxlines]{reledpar}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage {xepersian}
\usepackage{bidi}
\makeatletter
\let\footnoteruleA=\right@footnoterule
\let\Afootnoterule=\right@footnoterule
\makeatother
\Xbeforeinserting{\RTL}

\settextfont {Arabic Typesetting}
\numberpstarttrue
\setRlineflag{}
\renewcommand{\rbracket}{\textnormal{\thinspace :}}

\theledlanguageL
\Xwraplemma[A]{\RL}
\bhookgroupX[A]{\RTL}
\Xbhooknote[A]{\unsetRTL}
\rightfootnoterule

\Xbeforeinserting{\RTL}
\unsetLTR
\arrangementX[A]{threecol}

\Xbeforeinserting[A]{\RTL}
\Xwraplemma{\RL}
\Xragged[A]{R}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}


\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
        \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering      
                      \pstart
\begin{center}
\Large
یٓو فی الأدویة المسهلة و‌الجوارشنات المسهلة
\end{center}
\large  صنعة مسهل معمول کالجوارشن یسهل البلغم
\normalsize
شمشیر/
\ledleftnote{ت-۷۷و}
 و‌هو‌الهال و‌أنیسون من کل واحد وزن درهم دارصینی و‌ملح هندی و‌سقمونیا من کل واحد نصف درهم دارفلفل دانق و‌نصف سکر أربعة دراهم یدق الأدویة و‌ینخل و‌الشربة أربعة دراهم بماء فاتر جملة الأدویة سبعة
\pend    
\pstart    \large
جوارشن طیب مسهل
\normalsize
تربذ أبیض مدقوق منخول \edtext{درهمان}{\Afootnote{درهمین}} قرنفل جوزبوا و‌زعفران و‌عود من کل واحد دانق و‌نصف سقمونیا قیراط عسل الطبرزد ثلٰثة دراهم یخلط و‌یسقی و‌هو‌شربة واحدة جملة الأدویة ثمانیة
\pend    
\pstart    \large
مسهل آخر للمحرورین المزاج
\normalsize
تربذ وزن مثقال سقمونیا دانق ورد یابس و‌طباشیر و‌زعفران من کل واحد دانق و‌نصف عسل الطبرزد ثلٰثة دراهم یخلط و‌هو‌شربة واحدة جملة الأدویة خمسة
\pend    
\pstart    \large
مسهل یسهل المرار الأصفر و‌هو‌طیب 
\normalsize
سکر العشر عشرة دراهم سقمونیا درهم و‌‌دانقان\edtext{دانقان}{\Afootnote{دانقین}} یدق و‌ینخل و‌یلت بدهن اللوز الحلو ‌أو‌یسقی منه وزن ثلٰثة دراهم بجلاب و‌قوم آخر یخلطون فیه \edtext{شیئاً}{\Afootnote{شیء}} من زعفران یسیر جملة الأدویة إثنین/
\ledleftnote{ت-۷۷ظ}
\pend    
\pstart    \large
مسهل یتخذ بلوز حلو ‌فائق جید بالغ
\normalsize
یؤخذ لوز حلو‌ مقشر من قشریه و‌دارصینی من کل واحد وزن درهم تربذ وزن درهمین سقمونیا دانقین یدق و‌ینخل و‌یعجن بعسل و‌الشربة وزن أربعة دراهم فی الصیف بماء بارد و‌فی الشتاء بماء فاتر و‌جملة الأدویة أربعة
\pend    
\pstart    \large
مسهل متخذ من التربذ یسهل الخلط اللعابی البارد و‌الزجاجی
تربذ و‌‌زنجبیل و‌سکر أجزاء متساویة و‌الشربة ثلٰثة دراهم بشراب ممزوج و‌جملة الأدویة ثلٰثة
\pend      
                   \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
   \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
         \pstart           
            \begin{center}
            \Large
الباب السادس عشر 
       \\
       القول فی الإسهالات و‌\edtext{الجوارشنات}{\Afootnote{در سراسر باب حاضر، این کلمه در نسخه ل «جوارشن» و‌در نسخه ب «جوارش» ضبط شده است.}} المسهلة
       \end{center}
        \large
       و‌أول \edtext{‌ذٰلك}{\Afootnote{ب: +صنعة}} دواء مسهل یعمل مثل الجوارشن یسهل البلغم فائق جید 
\normalsize
يؤخذ ششمیر و‌ هو‌هیل و‌أنیسون من کل واحد وزن درهم دارصینی و‌‌ملح هندی‌ و‌سقمونیا من کل واحد نصف درهم دارفلفل دانقان سکر أربعة دراهم یدق و‌ینخل و‌یعطی الشربة أربعة دراهم بماء حار و‌جملة الأدویة سبعة عقاقیر
\pend
            \pstart
                \large
صنعة جوارش طیب مسهل 
\normalsize
تربذ أبیض مدقوق منخول درهمان قرنفل و‌جوزبوا و‌زعفران و‌عود من کل واحد دانقان سقمونیا نصف دانق عسل الطبرزد ثلٰثة دراهم یخلط و‌یعطی جمیعاً شربة واحدة. \edtext{الجملة ستة}{\Afootnote{ب: +إن شاء الله تعالی}}
\pend
            \pstart   \large
صنعة دواء مسهل آخر لمن کان مزاجه حاراً
\normalsize
تربذ مثقال واحد سقمونیا دانق ورد یابس و‌طباشیر و‌زعفران من کل واحد دانق و‌نصف عسل الطبرزد ثلٰثة دراهم یخلط و‌یعطی کلها شربة واحدة و‌جملة الأدویة خمسة
\pend
            \pstart
                \large
صنعة دواء مسهل للمرة الصفراء طیب 
\normalsize
سکر العشر عشرة دراهم سقمونیا درهم و‌دانقان یدق و‌ینخل و‌یلت بدهن اللوز الحلو ‌‌و‌‌یعطی منه وزن ثلٰثة دراهم بجلاب و‌قوم یخلطون فیه أیضاً زعفراناً یسیراً و‌‌الأدویة إثنان
\pend
            \pstart
                \large
صنعة دواء مسهل یعمل باللوز الحلو‌ فائق 
\normalsize
لوز حلو مقشر من قشریه و‌دارصینی من کل واحد وزن درهم تربذ جید درهمان سقمونیا دانقان یدق و‌ینخل و‌یعجن بعسل و‌یعطی الشربة منه أربعة دراهم فی الصیف بماء بارد و‌فی الشتاء بماء حار و‌جملة الأدویة أربعة|
\ledrightnote{ب-۸۷ظ}
\pend
            \pstart    \large
صنعة دواء آخر یسهل. یعمل بالتربذ یصلح للخلط البلغمانی البارد الزجاجی مجرب
\normalsize
یؤخذ تربذ و‌زنجبیل و‌سکر بالسویة یدق و‌ینخل و‌یعطی الشربة منه ثلٰثة دراهم بطلاء ممزوج و‌جملة الأدویة ثلٰثة
\pend   
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
\end{pages} 
\Pages
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is quite difficult for me to answer, as I don't read arabic, and all the glyph does not mean anything for me. Also, your code contain multiple call of the same hook (=reledmac setting command), as so it is quite difficult to understand what you wanted to produce. May I suggest you to group all your setting specific to critical notes in one block, an those related to  familiar not in an other one.

However, it seems me that

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\usepackage[series={A}]{reledmac}
\usepackage[top=3cm,left=5cm,right=4cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[shiftedpstarts,nomaxlines]{reledpar}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage {xepersian}
\usepackage{bidi}
\makeatletter
\let\Afootnoterule=\right@footnoterule
\makeatother

\settextfont {Arabic Typesetting}
\numberpstarttrue
\setRlineflag{}
\renewcommand{\rbracket}{\textnormal{\thinspace :}}

\Xbeforeinserting{\RTL}
\Xwraplemma[A]{\RL}
\Xbhooknote[A]{\RTL}
\Xbeforeinserting{\RTL}
%\Xragged[A]{R}
%\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}




\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
        \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
                      \pstart
\begin{center}
\Large
یٓو فی الأدویة المسهلة و‌الجوارشنات المسهلة
\end{center}
\large  صنعة مسهل معمول کالجوارشن یسهل البلغم
\normalsize
شمشیر/
\ledleftnote{ت-۷۷و}
 و‌هو‌الهال و‌أنیسون من کل واحد وزن درهم دارصینی و‌ملح هندی و‌سقمونیا من کل واحد نصف درهم دارفلفل دانق و‌نصف سکر أربعة دراهم یدق الأدویة و‌ینخل و‌الشربة أربعة دراهم بماء فاتر جملة الأدویة سبعة
\pend
\pstart    \large
جوارشن طیب مسهل
\normalsize
تربذ أبیض مدقوق منخول \edtext{درهمان}{\Afootnote{درهمین}} قرنفل جوزبوا و‌زعفران و‌عود من کل واحد دانق و‌نصف سقمونیا قیراط عسل الطبرزد ثلٰثة دراهم یخلط و‌یسقی و‌هو‌شربة واحدة جملة الأدویة ثمانیة
\pend
\pstart    \large
مسهل آخر للمحرورین المزاج
\normalsize
تربذ وزن مثقال سقمونیا دانق ورد یابس و‌طباشیر و‌زعفران من کل واحد دانق و‌نصف عسل الطبرزد ثلٰثة دراهم یخلط و‌هو‌شربة واحدة جملة الأدویة خمسة
\pend
\pstart    \large
مسهل یسهل المرار الأصفر و‌هو‌طیب
\normalsize
سکر العشر عشرة دراهم سقمونیا درهم و‌‌دانقان\edtext{دانقان}{\Afootnote{دانقین}} یدق و‌ینخل و‌یلت بدهن اللوز الحلو ‌أو‌یسقی منه وزن ثلٰثة دراهم بجلاب و‌قوم آخر یخلطون فیه \edtext{شیئاً}{\Afootnote{شیء}} من زعفران یسیر جملة الأدویة إثنین/
\ledleftnote{ت-۷۷ظ}
\pend
\pstart    \large
مسهل یتخذ بلوز حلو ‌فائق جید بالغ
\normalsize
یؤخذ لوز حلو‌ مقشر من قشریه و‌دارصینی من کل واحد وزن درهم تربذ وزن درهمین سقمونیا دانقین یدق و‌ینخل و‌یعجن بعسل و‌الشربة وزن أربعة دراهم فی الصیف بماء بارد و‌فی الشتاء بماء فاتر و‌جملة الأدویة أربعة
\pend
\pstart    \large
مسهل متخذ من التربذ یسهل الخلط اللعابی البارد و‌الزجاجی
تربذ و‌‌زنجبیل و‌سکر أجزاء متساویة و‌الشربة ثلٰثة دراهم بشراب ممزوج و‌جملة الأدویة ثلٰثة
\pend
                   \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
   \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
         \pstart
            \begin{center}
            \Large
الباب السادس عشر
       \\
       القول فی الإسهالات و‌\edtext{الجوارشنات}{\Afootnote{در سراسر باب حاضر، این کلمه در نسخه ل «جوارشن» و‌در نسخه ب «جوارش» ضبط شده است.}} المسهلة
       \end{center}
        \large
       و‌أول \edtext{‌ذٰلك}{\Afootnote{ب: +صنعة}} دواء مسهل یعمل مثل الجوارشن یسهل البلغم فائق جید
\normalsize
يؤخذ ششمیر و‌ هو‌هیل و‌أنیسون من کل واحد وزن درهم دارصینی و‌‌ملح هندی‌ و‌سقمونیا من کل واحد نصف درهم دارفلفل دانقان سکر أربعة دراهم یدق و‌ینخل و‌یعطی الشربة أربعة دراهم بماء حار و‌جملة الأدویة سبعة عقاقیر
\pend
            \pstart
                \large
صنعة جوارش طیب مسهل
\normalsize
تربذ أبیض مدقوق منخول درهمان قرنفل و‌جوزبوا و‌زعفران و‌عود من کل واحد دانقان سقمونیا نصف دانق عسل الطبرزد ثلٰثة دراهم یخلط و‌یعطی جمیعاً شربة واحدة. \edtext{الجملة ستة}{\Afootnote{ب: +إن شاء الله تعالی}}
\pend
            \pstart   \large
صنعة دواء مسهل آخر لمن کان مزاجه حاراً
\normalsize
تربذ مثقال واحد سقمونیا دانق ورد یابس و‌طباشیر و‌زعفران من کل واحد دانق و‌نصف عسل الطبرزد ثلٰثة دراهم یخلط و‌یعطی کلها شربة واحدة و‌جملة الأدویة خمسة
\pend
            \pstart
                \large
صنعة دواء مسهل للمرة الصفراء طیب
\normalsize
سکر العشر عشرة دراهم سقمونیا درهم و‌دانقان یدق و‌ینخل و‌یلت بدهن اللوز الحلو ‌‌و‌‌یعطی منه وزن ثلٰثة دراهم بجلاب و‌قوم یخلطون فیه أیضاً زعفراناً یسیراً و‌‌الأدویة إثنان
\pend
            \pstart
                \large
صنعة دواء مسهل یعمل باللوز الحلو‌ فائق
\normalsize
لوز حلو مقشر من قشریه و‌دارصینی من کل واحد وزن درهم تربذ جید درهمان سقمونیا دانقان یدق و‌ینخل و‌یعجن بعسل و‌یعطی الشربة منه أربعة دراهم فی الصیف بماء بارد و‌فی الشتاء بماء حار و‌جملة الأدویة أربعة|
\ledrightnote{ب-۸۷ظ}
\pend
            \pstart    \large
صنعة دواء آخر یسهل. یعمل بالتربذ یصلح للخلط البلغمانی البارد الزجاجی مجرب
\normalsize
یؤخذ تربذ و‌زنجبیل و‌سکر بالسویة یدق و‌ینخل و‌یعطی الشربة منه ثلٰثة دراهم بطلاء ممزوج و‌جملة الأدویة ثلٰثة
\pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

If that is not the case, could you send me a MWE using latin character, despite it is written RTL?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I mean that the first critical footnote is written in the left side of line and the next footnote is at the right side of first and so... . Each of footnotes are correct but the order of footnotes is from left to right. Can you help me please?

Comment: please, send me by email a mwe with latin character instead of arabic. It will be difficult for me in other case.

Comment: I couldn't find your E-mail address. 
please help me. It is very important for me. thanks.

Comment: on reledmac handbook, you will find it. maieul [at] maieul [dot] net