# Can't set critical notes RTL with verse numbers

Tags: hebrew, right-to-left, reledmac, reledpar

Running XeLaTeX, I'm trying to typeset a critical edition of a Hebrew-script, Bible-style text (with verse numbers instead of line numbers). I can't seem to get the footnotes to be RTL.

I have made the first words of verse 1 and verse 2, and a word from the second line of verse 2, into critical notes, but the lemma from verse 1 is leftmost on the line (and has no verse number attached); the next footnote from verse 2 is in the middle, labelled as verse 1, and the last footnote is rightmost on the line, labelled as verse 1.
Each note themselves read correctly RTL, but each note is being positioned so the line itself is LTR.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage[noresetlinenumannotation, series={A}, noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}

\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}[Scale=0.9]{David CLM}

\Xarrangement{paragraph}
\Xbeforeinserting{\RTL}
\Xwrapcontent{\texthebrew}
\Xwraplemma{\RL}

\newcommand{\bv}[1]{\linenumannotation{#1}}
\makeatletter
\Xwraplinenumannotation{\@firstofone}
\renewcommand{\linenumrep}[1]{}
\makeatother
\Xnoidenticallinenumannotation

\begin{document}
  \firstlinenum{1}
  \linenumincrement{1}
  \selectlanguage{hebrew}
  \beginnumbering
    \pstart
      \bv{1} \edtext{פתגמי}{\Afootnote{פת}} נבואה דאיתנבי קהלת הוא שלמה בר דוד מלכא דהוה בירושלם:
      \bv{2} \edtext{כד}{\Afootnote{כ}} חזא שלמה מלכא דישראל ברוח נבואה ית מלכות  \edtext{רחבעם}{\Afootnote{רח}} בריה דעתיד לאיתפלגא עם ירבעם בר נבט וית ירושלם ובית  
    \pend
  \endnumbering
\end{document}
```

What I am trying to achieve is for the critical notes to look something like:

[image]

I see this has been asked a couple of months ago, but no answer was given: [Typesetting critical footnotes in reledpar package from right to left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481430/typesetting-critical-footnotes-in-reledpar-package-from-right-to-left)

P.S. Link to the font is https://opensiddur.org/wp-content/uploads/fonts/display-font-charmap.php?fnt=DavidCLM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you'd have better luck using `babel` and `lualatex` instead of `polyglossia` and `xelatex`. `babel`'s RTL support with `lualatex` is maturing rapidly and often gives better outcomes than `polyglossia`+`bidi`+`xelatex` now.

## MWE

The footnotes are not broken up exactly as you want them, but they are RTL.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noresetlinenumannotation, series={A}, noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{hebrew}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Scale=0.9]{David CLM Medium}
\Xarrangement{paragraph}
\newcommand{\bv}[1]{\linenumannotation{#1}}
\makeatletter
\Xwraplinenumannotation{\@firstofone}
\renewcommand{\linenumrep}[1]{}
\makeatother
\Xnoidenticallinenumannotation
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\beginnumbering
  \pstart
    \bv{1} \edtext{פתגמי}{\Afootnote{פת}} נבואה דאיתנבי קהלת הוא שלמה בר דוד מלכא דהוה בירושלם:
    \bv{2} \edtext{כד}{\Afootnote{כ}} חזא שלמה מלכא דישראל ברוח נבואה ית מלכות  \edtext{רחבעם}{\Afootnote{רח}} בריה דעתיד לאיתפלגא עם ירבעם בר נבט וית ירושלם ובית  
  \pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]